# How do I translate: ich komme nicht dagegen an

Tags: idiom, adverb

This is from the subtitles of the opening scene of the film *Hannah and her Sisters*. The line that Michael Caine says is "I can't help it", but *dagegen* is often used in the context of a discussion or debate ("ich bin dagegen", "I'm against it").

Is the real meaning "I can't fight it"?

There is also the possibility that whoever wrote the subtitles miss-translated, and it should just be something like "ich kann es nicht helfen".

---- UPDATE ----

(Entschuldigung Sie bitte, mein Deutsch ist noch schrecklich)

Ja, der Film hat englisches Audio und deutsche Untertitel, und ich verstehe die Wortwahl des Übersetzers nicht. Ich gedacht, es sei vielleicht kontextbezogen, wie in diesem Beispiel:

> Ich hatte einen Autounfall.  Ich kann mir nicht helfen.
>
> I had a car accident.  I can't help it.

und nicht wie hier:

> Ich liebe sie.  Ich komme nicht dagegen an.
>
> I love her.  I can't help it.

Danke für Ihre Antworten.

Comment: Ich verstehe das Setting nicht ganz. Du hast den Film auf Deutsch gesehen mit deutschen Untertiteln? Wie hängt "I can't help it" mit "dagegen" zusammen? Im Deutschen gibt es übrigens die dem "I can't help it" ähnliche Phrase "Ich kann mir nicht helfen". "Ich kann es nicht helfen" ist jedenfalls falsch. Er/sie/es, 3. Person singular, sächlich: "Ich kann ihm (dem Kätzchen) nicht helfen."

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe das so verstanden, dass der Film mit englischem Audio und deutschen Untertiteln lief und dabei die Diskrepanz auffiel.

Comment: @Arsak: Aber dann wäre doch die wahre Bedeutung auf Englisch doch einfach zu erhören gewesen.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist wohl mehr ein Fall von "ich hätte das anders übersetzt als der Profi - welche Übersetzung ist treffender?"

Comment: @Arsak: Richard hat das Interesse an der Frage offenbar verloren. Wenn die Originalaussage "I can't help it" ist, dann kann "I can't fight it" nur besser sein, wenn man es besser weiß als der Drehbuchautor. Übersetzer sind da gar nicht im Spiel.

Comment: Lieber Richard, ich habe deine Rechtschreibung und Grammatik verbessert. Falls du dazu Fragen hast, erkläre ich auch gerne die vorgenommenen Korrekturen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ich komme nicht dagegen an" could be literally translated "There is too much resistance, I cannot overcome it."

"I can't help it" is (by [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/I%20can't%20help%20it)) translated as "Ich kann es nicht ändern." So whatever I do, the referenced situation/ state will stay the same.

Linked together there is:

> Ich kann die Situation nicht ändern, der Widerstand ist zu stark für mich und meine Möglichkeiten.

for a longer english sentence:

> I cannot help it, the resistance is too strong for me and my possibilities.

Regarding the Update and it's two new examples:

Yes, "I can't help it" has a contextual translation:

> Ich hatte einen Autounfall. **Ich kann mir nicht helfen.**

may refer to the description that

- I have no clue why it happened (=from my awareness of the circumstances I didn't see it coming)
- I can't change the current situation alone [note: that would be very "nonidiomatic" and neutral which I consider as rarely used]
- I cannot describe it in a positive way - and it requires a longer sentence like "Ich kann mir nicht helfen, aber das ist schon Mist [und jemand anders ist schuld]"

On the contrary second example:

> Ich liebe sie. **Ich komme nicht dagegen an.**

In this context the meaning is that my head tells me somewhat rational arguments why I should not consider to have a (loving) relationship to her. So I try to resist my feelings of my heart - and I know my heart will keep telling my that I love her.

So it is somewhat "being unable" just the reason differs.

"Ich kann es nicht helfen." is simply wrong and for the original question I would need the entire transcription as context.

Comment: -1: your translation of "I can't help it" is wrong. Better look it up before you guess.

Comment: @infinitezero: as far as I understood the question while I answered it was requested to know how "ich komme nicht dagegen an" could be translated and that the english original uses "I can't help it". As far as I read your comment, you spared the correct translation so I asked leo.org which means "ich kann es nicht ändern". I see a difference and stay surprised by your way of helping.

Comment: Changed it to +1 now. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Ich komme nicht dagegen an" is close to "I can't stem the tide".

It *doesn't imply* "I can't fight it" but rather "I am not able to prevail".

By the way, I find it interesting how the should-be synonyms "I am unable to prevail" and "I cannot prevail" have subtly different meanings of their own:

- "not able" reports the result of a struggle,
- "unable" is a quality of the speaker,
- "cannot" is a statement about an absolute impossibility.

Answer (score 1):

Laut dict.cc heißt „ich kann jemanden/etwas ankommen“

> to cope with someone/be able to fight something.

Diese Übersetzung scheint mit dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen#Bedeutung5) übereinzustimmen:

> gegen jemanden etwas aufkommen, sich durchsetzen, jemandem, einer Sache beikommen
>
> Beispiel: gegen ihn, gegen die Entwicklung kann man nicht, nur schwer ankommen.